# Need help planning reroute of cold water line

Tags: plumbing, pex, copper

Recently purchased a house and am in the middle of replacing the lead water service line along with what I think are more lead pipes.

From the water service line, the pipe goes underground then re-emerges ~40 feet later to convert to 1/2" pex line. That pex line splits on a 't' adapter. The first line supplies cold water to the house and travels ~10 feet up to the 1st floor and ~20 feet for the second floor. The second line doubles back ~40 feet to reach the water heater, converts the cold to hot water then heads off to its final destination.

[image: Plumbing schematic overview]

The longest distance traveled by cold water is between 50 and 60-ish feet while hot water is 90 and 100 feet.

No change in pressure/flow anywhere in the house unless the washing machine or dishwasher are in use. Both showers can be on at the same time.

I'm planning on adding a new pex or copper line that will be above ground and parallel to the cold-water line that goes to the water heater.

1. Will pressure/flow change if i only use 1/2" line or should i use 40 feet of 3/4" line then convert to 1/2"?
2. Is this plumbing route okay? From the water meter I was thinking of putting put in a FIP to 1/2" ball value, three or four inches of pipe, an elbow to turn up, 3 feet of pipe,  an elbow to turn back parallel above the meter, then a third  elbow to go across to the other end of the basement. Finally I’ll have another elbow to point down then attach to the existing T line. This will be visualized in the additional pics
3. Will the additional elbows change the pressure/flow at all?

[image: first part of proposed route]

[image: second part of proposed route]

Comment: A general rule our city designers use the general rule that a 90" elbow bend has a pressure drop equivalent of 30 to 50 pipe-diameters length of straight pipe. I do not know how accurate this is but that is what I was told.

Comment: What size is your feed from the water company?

Comment: 3/4" from the street and the new water meter im getting is 3/4" on both sides

Answer (score 1):

Your new plan will work. You have a flow problem when the dishwasher and or clothes washer run because your 3/4" feed reduced to 1/2" and then taps off to those feeds and the feed back to the water heater. I'd run a 3/4" new line and tap off it to the upstairs bath, kitchen and water heater run independently. Don't reduce to 1/2" and then tap off. Great idea to use ball valves

Comment: Thank you! I can't go 3/4" all the way because most of the exisitng piping is 1/2", but i will stick with 3/4" for the line i can replace.